# How to check if a variable is defined and search for two patterns within an array using perl regex?

Tags: perl

How to check if a variable is defined and search for two patterns within an array using perl regex?

```
$/ = ""; # paragraph mode

__Data__
#SCSI_test         # put this line into  @arrayNewLines      
kdkdkdkdkdkdkdkd
dkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkd
- ccccccccccccccc  # put this line into @arrayNewLines


  while(<FILEREAD>)
  {
      chomp;
      my @arrayOld = split('\n',$_);

      foreach my $i (0 .. $#arrayOld) # using the foreach of index to remove the lines.
      {
            if($arrayOld[$i] =~ /-(.*)/ || /\#(.*)/)
            {
                 my @arrayNewLines = $arrayOld[$i];
                 splice @arrayOld,$i,1;             # remove lines from arrayOld
                 print "@arrayNewLines\n";
            }
                 print "@arrayOld\n";
      }
   }
```

This code does not work in terms of placing each type of - or # lines into the same @arrayNewLines array. It only works on the first (/-(.*)/) pattern and does not work on the second (/#(.*)/). I need it to search on both patterns and defined the $arrayOld[i] variable to prevent use of uninitiilize messages.
I want to defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($arrayOld[$i] =~ /-(.*)/ || /\#(.*)/)
```

This does not work the way you think it does, for the same reason that this wouldn't either:

```
if($x == 1 || 2)
```

Use this instead:

```
if($arrayOld[$i] =~ /-(.*)/ || $arrayOld[$i] =~ /\#(.*)/)
```

Just as you'd use this:

```
if($x == 1 || $x == 2)
```

Comment: thanks duskwuff, that works but I need to get rid of the use of uninitialized value messages

Comment: @Joseph Walker: duskwuff offers a great solution whose disjuncts can be combined within a single regex after a test for uninitialized vars (so you won't get those messages): `if($arrayOld[$i] && $arrayOld[$i] =~ /-|\#(.*)/)`